# Apollo/GraphQL field type for object with dynamic keys

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Let's say my graphql server wants to fetch the following data as JSON where `person3` and `person5` are some id's:

```
"persons": {
  "person3": {
    "id": "person3",
    "name": "Mike"
  },
  "person5": {
    "id": "person5",
    "name": "Lisa"
  }
}
```

**Question**: How to create the schema type definition with apollo?

The keys `person3` and `person5` here are dynamically generated depending on my query (i.e. the `area` used in the query). So at another time I might get `person1`, `person2`, `person3` returned.
As you see `persons` is not an Iterable, so the following won't work as a graphql type definition I did with apollo:

```
type Person {
  id: String
  name: String
}
type Query {
  persons(area: String): [Person]
}
```

The keys in the `persons` object may always be different.

One solution of course would be to transform the incoming JSON data to use an array for `persons`, but is there no way to work with the data as such?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `b` and `g` being `dynamically generated depending on my query`? Does the presence of one or the other depend on the fields present in the request?

Comment: @DanielRearden So `b` and `g` are id's. Perhaps I should make that clearer in the question. The query will contain options to only get a subset of people, so for one query the response will contain people with id's `a`, `b`, `c` and for another query for example `b` and `g` as in the question.

Comment: @DanielRearden I now changed `b` to `person3` and `g` to `person 5` and added some text and a variable to make it clearer. The query will contain options to only get a subset of people as now outlined in the text.

Comment: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/101

Answer (score 39, accepted):

GraphQL relies on both the server and the client knowing ahead of time what fields are available available for each type. In some cases, the client can discover those fields (via introspection), but for the server, they always need to be known ahead of time. So to somehow dynamically generate those fields based on the returned data is not really possible.

You **could** utilize a custom [JSON scalar](https://github.com/taion/graphql-type-json) (graphql-type-json module) and return that for your query:

```
type Query {
  persons(area: String): JSON
}
```

By utilizing JSON, you bypass the requirement for the returned data to fit any specific structure, so you can send back whatever you want as long it's properly formatted JSON.

Of course, there's significant disadvantages in doing this. For example, you lose the safety net provided by the type(s) you would have previously used (literally any structure could be returned, and if you're returning the wrong one, you won't find out about it until the client tries to use it and fails). You also lose the ability to use resolvers for any fields within the returned data.

But... your funeral :)

As an aside, I would consider flattening out the data into an array (like you suggested in your question) before sending it back to the client. If you're writing the client code, and working with a dynamically-sized list of customers, chances are an array will be much easier to work with rather than an object keyed by id. If you're using React, for example, and displaying a component for each customer, you'll end up converting that object to an array to map it anyway. In designing your API, I would make client usability a higher consideration than avoiding additional processing of your data.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I transform the incoming data from the server. FYI: The reason for objects with ids was faster retrieval on client side because it's just a lookup of an id to access a particular person.

Comment: My situation is returning validation errors via a Rails / GraphQL API. I don't know in advance what keys will have errors, hence I'm using a custom JSON scalar.

Comment: Actually I changed my approach to use nested arrays which allowed me to consistently return the fields with errors.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own `GraphQLScalarType` and precisely describe your object and your dynamic keys, what you allow and what you do not allow or transform.

See https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlscalartype

You can have a look at [taion/graphql-type-json](https://github.com/taion/graphql-type-json) where he creates a Scalar that allows and transforms any kind of content:

https://github.com/taion/graphql-type-json/blob/master/src/index.js

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with dynamic keys in a schema, and ended up going with a solution like this:

```
query lookupPersons {
  persons {
    personKeys
    person3: personValue(key: "person3") {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

returns:

```
{
  data: {
    persons: {
      personKeys: ["person1", "person2", "person3"]
      person3: {
        id: "person3"
        name: "Mike"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

by shifting the complexity to the query, it simplifies the response shape.
the advantage compared to the JSON approach is it doesn't need any deserialisation from the client

**Additional info for Venryx:** a possible schema to fit my query looks like this:

```
type Person {
  id: String
  name: String
}

type PersonsResult {
  personKeys: [String]
  personValue(key: String): Person
}

type Query {
  persons(area: String): PersonsResult
}
```

As an aside, if your data set for persons gets large enough, you're going to probably want pagination on `personKeys` as well, at which point, you should look into https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm

Comment: What does the server-side GraphQL schema look like for this? It's a bit unclear to me. (you only show the query's client-provided shape, and the server's response)